# Python convert List[str] to Dict[str, str] using ArgumentParser

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I need to parse command line argument - convert `List[str]` to `Dict[str, str]`

```
['key1=value1', 'key2=value2'] -> {key1: value1, key2:value2}
```

I use the following code:

```
 parser.add_argument(
        '--model-config',
        nargs='+',
        type=model_config_str_to_dict        
    )
```

where `model_config_str_to_dict(model_config: List[str])` is a function to convert list to dict. But instead of `List[str]` I get `str` for the model_config parameter.

My question is how can I parse --model-config parameter to convert it to dict?

Comment: It's a good idea when debugging a function like this to print the argument(s).  You need to know just what it is that `argparse` is passing `model_config_str_to_dict`.  The docs should be clear that the `type` function should expect a string.  Also when asking `argparse` questions we like to see the commandline, or equivalent `parse_args(...)` expression.  I think we can deduce what you are using, but we shouldn't have to do that.  There too much room for wrong deductions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `type` argument is applied to each of the inputs following `--model-config` **before** they are appended to a list that is stored in the parsed arguments as the attribute `.model_config`.  In other words, the value of `model_config` will be `List[model_config_str_to_dict(mc_arg)]`, not `model_config_str_to_dict(List[mc_arg])`

As an example:

```py
import argparse

def model_config_split(s):
    k, v = s.split('=', 1)
    return (k, v)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument( '--model-config',
        nargs='+',
        type=model_config_str_to_dict)

args = parser.parse_args(['--model-config', 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2'])
print(args.model_config)

# prints:
# [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]
```

If you want to convert this to a dictionary, you can do that **after** parsing the arguments.

```
args.model_config = dict(args.model_config)
print(args.model_config)

# prints:
# {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```